# SQL - Select n number of each row value in a column?

Tags: sql, select

I have code -

```
SELECT 
        class, revenue
FROM tblproduct
```

With the following data -

```
      class    revenue 
1          7 136.9900    
2          7  24.0984    
3       1318  61.9900    
4       1318  39.9800    
5          7  32.9800   
6        1318 107.6674
```

Is there a way to only select a certain count of each unique row in the class column? So for example, only select a count of two would have the following output -

```
           class   revenue 
    1          7 136.9900    
    2          7  24.0984    
    3       1318  61.9900    
    4       1318  39.9800
```

Any tips will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by class order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: @Sharkbait If this works, please accept this post as the answer. See this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work to learn how to do this.